How do I add a top offset to sticky headers?
In Jetpack Compose, I have a LazyColumn with multiple stickyHeader items. By default, the stickyHeader items will stick to the top of the LazyColumn as you scroll down. Is there a way to alter this behavior so that the stickyHeader items don't stick to the top of the LazyColumn, but rather 100 pixels from the top?
Note that I don't want any offset applied to the stickyHeader items until they reach 100 pixels from the top.

You can simply add a Spacer to the stickyHeader or apply a padding:
stickyHeader {
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(25.dp))
    Text(
        text = "Sticky Header", 
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.Green))
}

Is that what you want?
Output:


Sorry for the confusion, the stickyHeader item(s) are not the first items in the LazyColumn and thus I don't want the offset to apply until each sticky header reaches 100 pixels from the top. I edited the main post to clarify.

This behavior can be achieved by using stickyHeader with .graphicsLayer { translationY = VALUE_PX }
For example:
stickyHeader {
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .graphicsLayer { translationY = headerOffset.value.toPx() }
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.Green)),
        text = "Sticky Header", 
}

And for headerOffset:
val headerOffset = remember(listState) {
    derivedStateOf {
        val maxOffsetDp = 56.dp
        if (listState.firstVisibleItemIndex != 0) return@derivedStateOf maxOffsetDp
        val firstItem = listState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull() ?: return@derivedStateOf 0.dp
        val leftDp = with(density) { (firstItem.size - firstItem.offset.absoluteValue).toDp() }
        (maxOffsetDp - leftDp).coerceAtLeast(0.dp)
    }
}

